# PHP Warning after upgrade from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.1.10

Tags: upgrade, composer, cli, magento-2.1.9

I'm having some issues with an **installation** of **Magento 2** that I'm upgrading from **2.1.9 to the 2.1.10** security update.

I'm following the [cli-upgrade](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) instructions.

I'm running all commands as root. I enabled maintenance mode, and ran `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.10 --noupdate` as specified. I then ran `composer update`, entered my auth keys, and manually cleared the `var` subdirectories.

As soon as I ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it threw this error.

```
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 60
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 60
```

It seems like most commands that I run end with the same issue.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

The file `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` is not found, which registers components from `app`, i.e. those that were installed manually.

I had the same issue and solved it by running `composer dump-autoload`. Alternatively, you can download the missing file from Github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (a missing Magento base file) usually happens when you tidy up your git repository or your installation fails midway or something along these lines.

Easiest (read: laziest) way to solve it is to wipe vendor folder and run `composer install`.